# Highcharts bar chart on wrong axis

Tags: highcharts

I know that a bar chart is just a rotated column chart. I make a number of different kinds of plots that all work with highcharts, including the columns charts. However, when I create a bar chart, the data is plotted from the bottom just as a column chart.

Is there something with the axes or the way that the data is set that would cause this? I use the standard setData command to set the data after the chart is created.

Comment: What's your chart option like?

Comment: Please replicate your chart as live demo.